# Fourier transform and covariant/contravariant vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, covariance

A Fourier transform of a function of $x$ is related by the following equation:

$$φ'(p) = \int_{}^{}φ(x) e^{ix·p} \mathrm{d}x.$$

Let's say that $x$ is a contravariant vector.  Does it follow that $p$ transforms as a covariant vector?

In other words, is it true that, if we transform $x \to x',$ then $p$ must transform as

$$
p'_\mu
=
\frac{
  \partial x^\nu
}{
  \partial x'^\mu
}
p_\nu
$$
so, as a result, I will have to replace all $p$ in $φ'(p)$ with $p'$ that is related by the above expression?

Comment: I would say that you are correct although it isn't really proper to talk about coordinates being co-/contravariant.